# How do I sort an array of docIds by the property in Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of Strings. These strings are documentIds for some documents in a collection in firebase Firestore. each document has a value called dateSent which is of type Date. Can I sort my array of strings by that data? Note that I am doing this in a onAppear method in one of my swiftui views.

Here is what I have tried so far but it doesn't do anything:

```
      @State var recievedDocIds = ["tutWYdAS3EOwwnP0mjgn", "oujk6JrsHPqfcJNiDpcm", "nsakKhckqKLVWlstPVcl", "BLHYTkTgr6c5Z3U7ojF6", "PXNqlL0GZnzPmL9W4blp", "PI02YrhSoNzW8dB8cCKP", "YDYoxHq4Vunlo7SjqFI5", "4w0eKGXaMkA17moJH3W0"]


      self.recievedDocIDs.sort{
                    var date1: Date? = nil
                    var date2: Date? = nil
                    Firestore.firestore().collection("kindMessages").document($0).getDocument(){document, error in
                        if let doc = document, doc.exists{
                            date1 = doc.data()?["dateSent"] as? Date ?? Date()
                        }
                    }
                    print("sorted: \(self.recievedDocIDs)")// this line does not get executed
                    Firestore.firestore().collection("kindMessages").document($1).getDocument(){document, error in
                        if let doc = document, doc.exists{
                            date2 = doc.data()?["dateSent"] as? Date ?? Date()
                        }
                    }
                    return date1 ?? Date() > date2 ?? Date()
                }
```

Comment: Firestore queries are asynchronous and return immediately.  The callbacks are invoked some time later, after the query completes.  Your code is not waiting for the results.

Comment: would you know a solution around that? should I put the queries inside a function?

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at how to handle async calls done from Firebase as shown in this [public blog](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93)

Comment: that fixed it thanks!